# Creating a group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have around 10 tables in an ssrs report and I need to add a group which includes them all. Is there a way to do that in ssrs?

I know how to create column and row groups within a single tablix, but I am not able to do the same for more than one tablix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a table with a single cell, then inserted a rectangle in it and then copy/pasted all the tables in there. Then added a row group and it works!!